# Microsoft Graph partial tenant consent

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a b2b app that has an international customer, where only one country of their organisation uses my software. I created a graph API integration with an application based permission, but this grants my app permission for every user across the organisation. Is it possible to have an admin consent authorization flow that only targets users from one country for example? It seems to be either everyone or just individuals, no middle ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no middle ground.
Your app can either access e.g. all users as itself (app permissions),
or it can access e.g. all users a user can access (delegated permissions).

And usually either a user can see all users or they cannot see any users (e.g. if the user has type Guest and guest permissions have been limited in the tenant).